# React: convertir componente de Clase a Funcional

Tags: reactjs

Qué tal? Tengo este código y necesito convertirlo de un componente de clase a un componente funcional pero tengo conocimientos demasiado básicos de React. Alguien podrá ayudarme a solucionarlo o al menos, orientarme un poco qué es lo que debería hacer? Cualquier consulta que pueda responderles si tienen alguna duda sobre lo que necesito hacer, quedo a disposición. Desde ya, muchas gracias!!

```
class Clock extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      // Estado privado del component
    this.state = {
         // Se genera una fecha como estado inicial del componente
        fecha: new Date(),
        edad: 0,
        nombre: "Martín",
        apellidos: "San José"
    };
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.timerID = setInterval (
        () => this.tick(), 1000
    );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval (this.timerID);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h2>
        Hora Actual:
        {this.state.fecha.toLocaleTimeString()}
        </h2>

        <h3>{this.state.nombre} {this.state.apellidos}</h3>
        <h1>Edad: {this.state.edad}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
tick(){
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        let edad = prevState.edad +1;
        return {
            ...prevState,
            fecha: new Date(),
            edad
        }
    });
}
}
export default Clock;
```

Comment: Es un componente pequeño que no te tardará mucho rehacerlo en un componentes funcional, todo lo que necesitas está en la documentación oficial de reactjs. Lo que necesitas saber es que las funciones del ciclo de vida de los componentes como `componentwillmount, componentdidmount` han sido reemplazados por `useEffect`, y el estado del componentes ahora se maneja con `useState`, Los componentes de declaran como función `export default function(props){  }`, lee [documentacion react](https://es.react.dev/learn/your-first-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Clock = () => {
  const [fecha, setFecha] = useState(new Date());
  const [edad, setEdad] = useState(0);
  const nombre = 'Martín';
  const apellidos = 'San José';

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerID = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerID);
    };
  }, []);

  const tick = () => {
    setFecha(new Date());
    setEdad((prevEdad) => prevEdad + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hora Actual: {fecha.toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
      <h3>{nombre} {apellidos}</h3>
      <h1>Edad: {edad}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Clock;
```

Te explico un poco que fué lo que hice:

1. Importé `useState` y `useEffect` de react. Estos son los hooks que
   utilizaremos en lugar de la clase y los métodos del ciclo de vida.
2. Eliminé el constructor y moví la inicialización del estado a través
   del hook `useState`. Ahora `fecha` y `edad` son estados locales en el
   componente funcional.
3. Reemplacé `componentDidMount` y `componentWillUnmount` por el hook
   `useEffect`. Dentro del useEffect, establecí el intervalo para llamar
   a la función tick cada segundo y limpiar el intervalo cuando el
   componente se desmonta.
4. Reemplacé `this.setState` con los setters proporcionados por `useState`
   para actualizar los estados fecha y edad.
5. Eliminé `prevState` ya que el estado se actualiza directamente en
   React.
6. En lugar de definir `nombre` y `apellidos` como parte del estado, los
   definí como variables dentro del componente funcional.

Recuerda leer la documentación de react [aquí](https://react.dev/)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a ambos por tomarse el tiempo de atender mi consulta y de explicarme detalladamente como resolverla. Me sirvió mucho para ir entendiendo el enfoque para resolver estas cuestiones en React. Soy nuevo en el foro y la verdad que da gusto encontrarse con gente que sabe tanto del tema. Muchas gracias nuevamente!!

Comment: @diegoignacio, la comunidad te agradecerá si [votas y aceptas la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), ya que esto garantiza a otros usuarios que la pregunta y la respuesta son de utilidad, además de que ayudas a quien se dio el tiempo de contestarte a subir su reputación. Bienvenido